# Java fastest way to determine most occuring color by scaling an image?

Tags: java, image, algorithm, colors

The solution should be rather easy, but since I have no experience in this field and could not find a clear cut solution I'm asking.

For a simple project I need to determine the most occuring color in all 4 corners of my screen.
I am at the point where I have a BufferedImage of all 4 corners but can't find a fast and efficient algorithm to determine the most occuring color(not the average!).

Comment: That's pretty broad. Do you mean that you want the most frequent color in each of the four quadrants of the image? Do you want those colors quantized somehow so that similar colors are treated as identical? For example, the colors (255,0,0) and (255,1,1), both of which are "red," would be considered the same color.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best bet would be to load all the colors you find into a `HashMap<Color, Integer>`, where every time you find an instance of a `Color`, you either add it to the map or increment that color's counter. Then take the max of all the integers when you're done.

More on HashMaps:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Your answer is right. However, don't answer AND say this is the wrong place for the question. If the question is too broad, flag it as such. If you want to answer it, do so. Don't do both.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for letting me know. Should I take the "broadness" statement out of my answer or go ahead and flag it?

Comment: The OP needs to decide what is meant by "the most occurring color". For example, if there are a lot of red pixels (255,0,0),  should pixels whose color is (255,0,1) - which I seriously doubt anyone could visually distinguish from red - be considered the same thing? It probably depends on what he is going to do with the result. Also, it is possible that there are very few pixels with the same value, depending on the colormap depth.

Comment: That's fair, but I feel like this is more of an algorithmic question than the specifics behind separating the colors. Whether or not they use java.awt.Color or some other definition of a color they decide (where maybe (255,0,1) is still red), this should still count the occurrences of each one.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I would take the broadness out of your answer. Especially because you managed to answer the question quite well with such a short answer, it probably isn't too broad. But in general, it should be one or the other. If it doesn't belong on SO, flag it and don't answer.

Comment: Alright, I've taken it out. Thanks for giving me some answering pointers; I'm rather new to participation on Stack Overflow myself.

Comment: This is indeed a solution I've tried since yesterday, but I managed to find a much simpler solution that works just as good. I scale the image down to 1x1 (which will become the most occuring color) and simply determine the color of that pixel. Thanks for the help anyways!